# What is the maximum Streetpass Plaza population?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza

I previously assumed that the Streetpass Plaza population was only limited by the system's memory, but the VIP Room feature says that

> Mii characters with VIP status will stay in your plaza no matter how
>   many more Mii characters arrive via StreetPass.

This implies that there is an actual limit to the number of Miis that I can keep in my plaza.

What is the maximum Streetpass Plaza population?

Answer (score 4):

You can have unlimited StreetPass tags for miis, BUT the amount of Miis displayed is limited to 3'000 I think (if you get more Miis, they won't get deleted, they will most likely be cycled from time to time).

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/625899-streetpass-mii-plaza/61866918)

Comment: I actually read the thread that you cited before asking the question. It only has a guess, but I'm looking for something more than that.